# Access Denied? JAVA

Tags: java, file-io, applet, file-permissions, accesscontrolexception

I'm making a game for my java class in school, and needed to write onto a file.  I copied some code from a working program I had made before, but whenever I rune it, I get a Access Denied error.  My java teacher said I have full read and write access to the file, but it still spits out the error.

The file Hiscore.txt does exist and is spelled exactly like that.

The error is in the method MakeOutputFile, sphecifically where the printwriter is initialized.  It does also occur in CheckOutputFile, but that method is currently commented out.

I'm new to this website, so I'm not quite sure how to put code, so the results will be quite shoddy.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: 
    access denied  ("java.io.FilePermission" "Hiscore.txt" "write")
```

### Code

```
 import java.awt.*;

 import java.awt.event.*;

 import javax.swing.*;

 import javax.swing.event.*;

 import java.io.File;

 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.Scanner;



public class TowerDefence extends JApplet implements MouseListener  {

 int xpos, ypos, money, attackspawn, attackcount, lives, attackerhealth, hiscore, 
laser;        // x,y location of current square

private DrawingArea canvas;    // JPanel canvas on which to draw grid

private int[][] numbers;     

private int[][] damage;

JPanel startscreen;

File ifile, ofile, qfile;

Scanner input, output, questionreader;

boolean start, play, checkhiscore, fileexists, end, inquestionstate;

long totaldamage;

Timer timer;

boolean [][] moved;

JButton button;

public File fargle;

PrintWriter makesOutput;

 //JButton begin;



 // Constructor

 public TowerDefence( ) {

   inquestionstate = false;

 JButton begin = new JButton ("BEGIN");

 //begin = new JButton("BEGIN");

 checkhiscore = false;

 xpos = ypos = attackcount = laser = 4;        

 button = new JButton("Double Damage for 15 seconds");

 money = 200;

 attackspawn = 0;

 totaldamage = 0;

 lives = 10;

 attackerhealth = 24;

 fileexists = true;

 numbers = new int[30][30];    

 damage = new int [20][20];

 moved = new boolean  [20][20];

 Timer timer;

 end = false;

 for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++){

     for (int j = 0; j< 20; j++){

         moved[i][j] = false;

         damage [i][j] = 0;

     }

 }

 for (int i = 0; i<30; i++){

     for (int j = 0; j<30; j++){

         numbers[i][j] = 0;

     }

 }

 start = false;

 play = false;

 ifile = new File("map.txt");

 ofile = new File ("hiscore.txt");

 qfile = new File("questions.txt");

 RepaintAction action = new RepaintAction();

 timer = new Timer(1000, action);

 timer.start();

 }

 private class RepaintAction implements ActionListener {

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

 repaint();  // Call the repaint() method in the panel class.

 }

 }// MANDATORY: required initialization of JApplet

 // MANDATORY: required initialization of JApplet

 public void init ( ) {

 canvas = new DrawingArea();                // create a new Drawing Area

 setContentPane(canvas);                    // connect the canvas to JApplet

 canvas.setBackground(Color.lightGray);    // make the background lightGray

 canvas.addMouseListener(this);

 canvas.requestFocus();                     // focus keyboard on JApplet'

 }

 // MANDATORY: Define DrawingArea as a JPanel

 class DrawingArea extends JPanel {

  JButton begin = new JButton ("BEGIN");

  JButton upgrade = new JButton ("upgrade");

  JComboBox selectmap = new JComboBox();

  String op1, op2 = "yodel";

  String askquestion;

  String option = "ocean";

  String findplace = "";

  JRadioButton option1, option2;

  JLabel question;

  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

  JFrame questionframe = new JFrame();



 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

     super.paintComponent(g);        // MANDATORY: Must be first method called.

     if (!play&&!end){

          ReadIt1();

          StartScreen(g);

          StartButton();

      }

     if (start){

             ReadIt();

     }
    if (play){

         ChangeAttackers();

         drawGrid(g);                    

         Attack(g);

         DamageCheck();

         if (attackspawn % 15 == 0){

             SpawnAttackers();

             ReadQuestions();

         }

         LifeCheck(g);

     }

       //  CheckOutputFile();

       //if (fileexists){

              MakeOutputFile();

         //}

  if (end){

     LifeCheck(g);

          }

 }

 public void ReadQuestions(){

   if(!inquestionstate){

   try{

     questionreader = new Scanner(qfile);

   }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

     System.out.println("ERROR: cannot open file map.txt");

     System.exit(1);

   }

   while (!findplace.equalsIgnoreCase(op2)){

           findplace = questionreader.nextLine();

           }

           askquestion = questionreader.nextLine();

           op1 = questionreader.nextLine();

           op2 = questionreader.nextLine();

           System.out.println(askquestion);

           System.out.println(op1);

           System.out.println(op2);

           question = new JLabel(askquestion);

           option1 = new JRadioButton(op1);

           option2 = new JRadioButton(op2);

           questionframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

           questionframe.removeAll();

           questionframe.getContentPane().add(question);

           questionframe.getContentPane().add(option1);

           questionframe.getContentPane().add(option2);

           questionframe.setVisible(true);

           inquestionstate = true;

           }

   }

 public void ReadIt1(){

     if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("ocean")){

         ifile = new File("oceanmap.txt");

     }

     else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("canyon")){

         ifile = new File("map.txt");

     }

 try{

     input = new Scanner(ifile);

 }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

     System.out.println("ERROR: cannot open file map.txt");

     System.exit(1);

 }

 for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){

     for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){

         numbers [j+5][i+5] = input.nextInt();

     }

 }

         input.close();

 }//end method ReadIt

 public void StartScreen(Graphics g){

      for (int row = 0; row < 20; row ++){

         for (int col = 0; col < 20; col ++){

             if (numbers[row+5][col+5] == 0&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("canyon")){

                 g.setColor(Color.green);

             }

             else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("canyon")){

                 g.setColor(Color.black);

             }

             else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("ocean")&&numbers[row+5][col+5] == 0){

                 g.setColor(Color.yellow);

             }

             else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("ocean")){

                 g.setColor(Color.cyan);

             }

             g.fillRect(30 + col *22, 30 + row * 22, 21, 21);

             g.setFont( new Font ("Serif", Font.BOLD, 48));

             g.setColor(Color.red);

             g.drawString("TOWER DEFENCE", 10,100);

         }

     }

         }

         public void StartButton(){

          selectmap.addItem("Ocean");

          selectmap.addItem("Canyon");

          begin.setVisible(true);

          begin.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

          this.setLayout(null);

          this.add(begin);

          begin.setBounds(0,468,500,32);
          selectmap.setVisible(true);

          this.add(selectmap);


          selectmap.setBounds(300,300, 100,25);

         }

 // Draw the numbers on the grid

 // Draw the Sudoku grid of rectangles

 public void LifeCheck(Graphics g){

   if(!inquestionstate){

         JButton upgrade = new JButton ("upgrade");

         upgrade.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

     for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){

         for (int j = 19; j<20; j++){

             if (numbers [i+5][j+5] == 2){

                 lives--;

                 numbers[i+5][j+5] = 1;
             }

         }

     }

     if (lives <=0){

         play = false;

         end = true;

         for (int row = 0; row < 20; row ++){

         for (int col = 0; col < 20; col ++){

             if (numbers[row+5][col+5] == 0&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Canyon")){

                 g.setColor(Color.green);

             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 1&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Canyon")){

                 g.setColor(Color.black);
             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 2){

                 g.setColor(Color.red);

             }

             else if (numbers[row+5][col+5] == 0&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Ocean")){

                 g.setColor(Color.yellow);

             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 1&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Ocean")){

                 g.setColor(Color.cyan);

             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 3){

                 g.setColor(Color.gray);

             }

            g.fillRect(30 + col *22, 30 + row * 22, 21, 21);

             g.setColor(Color.black);

             g.drawString("Money: "+money, 420,480);

             g.drawString("Lives: "+lives, 360,480);

             g.drawString("Laser: "+laser, 240,480);

             System.out.print(damage[row][col]);



         }

     }

     this.setLayout(null);

     this.add(upgrade);

    upgrade.setBounds(0, 475, 100, 25);

         Font myFont = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25);

         g.setFont(myFont);

         if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Ocean")){

               g.setColor(Color.red);

         }

         else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Canyon")){

             g.setColor(Color.cyan);

         }

         g.drawString("You have lost.  You lasted for " + attackspawn + "seconds.",10,100);

     }

     }

 }

 public void SpawnAttackers(){

   if(!inquestionstate){

     int currentspawn = 0;

     attackcount++;

     attackerhealth+=3;

     if (attackerhealth % 10 == 0){

         attackerhealth += (int)(attackerhealth*1.1);

                 }

    if (attackerhealth % 17 == 0){

         attackerhealth += (int)(attackerhealth*1.2);

    }

    if (attackerhealth % 12 == 0){

         attackerhealth += (int)(attackerhealth*1.3);

    }

    if (attackerhealth % 2 == 0){

         attackerhealth += 1+(int)(attackerhealth * 1.05);

    }

     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

         for (int j = 0; j< 20; j++){

             if (numbers [j+5][i+5] == 1){

                 numbers [j+5][i+5] = 2;

                 currentspawn++;

                 if (currentspawn == attackcount){

                     i = j = 100;

                 }

             }

         }

     }

     }

 }

 public void drawGrid(Graphics g) {

   if(!inquestionstate){

     money++;

     attackspawn++;

           }

     upgrade.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

     for (int row = 0; row < 20; row ++){

         for (int col = 0; col < 20; col ++){

             if (numbers[row+5][col+5] == 0&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Canyon")){

                 g.setColor(Color.green);

             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 1&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Canyon")){

                 g.setColor(Color.black);

             }

             else if (numbers[row+5][col+5] == 0&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Ocean")){

                 g.setColor(Color.yellow);

             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 1&&option.equalsIgnoreCase("Ocean")){

                 g.setColor(Color.cyan);

             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 2){

                 g.setColor(Color.red);

             }

             else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 3){

                 g.setColor(Color.gray);

             }

             g.fillRect(30 + col *22, 30 + row * 22, 21, 21);

             g.setColor(Color.black);

             g.drawString("Money: "+money, 420,480);

             g.drawString("Lives: "+lives, 360,480);

             g.drawString("Laser: "+laser, 240,480);

             g.drawString("Wave: " + (int)(attackspawn/15), 170,480);

             g.drawString("Total Damage: " + totaldamage, 170,20);

             System.out.print(damage[row][col]);

         }

         System.out.println();

     }

     this.setLayout(null);

     this.add(upgrade);

    upgrade.setBounds(0, 475, 100, 25);

     System.out.println();


 }

 public void ReadIt(){

   if(!inquestionstate){

     if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("ocean")){


         ifile = new File("oceanmap.txt");

     }

     else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("canyon")){

         ifile = new File("map.txt");

     }

 try{

     input = new Scanner(ifile);

 }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

     System.out.println("ERROR: cannot open file map.txt");

     System.exit(1);

 }

 for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){

     for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){

         numbers [j+5][i+5] = input.nextInt();

     }

 }

 start = false;

 play = true;

 input.close();

 }

 }//end method ReadIt

 public void DamageCheck(){

   if(!inquestionstate){

 for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){

     for (int j = 0; j<20; j++){

         if (damage[i][j] >=attackerhealth){

             numbers[i+5][j+5] = 1;

             damage[i][j] = 0;

             money+=25;

         }

     }

 }

 }

 }

 public void Attack(Graphics g){

   if(!inquestionstate){

     for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){

         for (int j = 0; j<20; j++){

             if (numbers [i+5][j+5] == 3){

                 for (int o = -3; o<4; o++){

                     for (int e = -3; e<4; e++){

                         if (numbers [i+o+5][j+e+5] == 2){

                             damage [i+o][j+e] +=laser;


                             totaldamage+=laser;
                             g.setColor(Color.white);

                             g.drawLine(40+j*22, 40+i*22, 40+(j+e)*22, 40+(i+o)*22);

                         }

                     }

                 }

             }

         }

     }

     }

 }

 public void ChangeAttackers(){

   if(!inquestionstate){

     for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){

         for (int j = 0; j<20; j++){

             moved[i][j] = false;

         }

     }

     for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){

         for (int j = 0; j<20; j++){

             if (numbers[i+5][j+5] == 2){

                 if (numbers[i+5][j+6] == 1&&moved[i][j] == false){

                     numbers [i+5][j+5] = 1;

                     numbers [i+5][j+6] = 2;

                     damage[i][j+1] = damage[i][j];

                     damage[i][j] = 0;

                     moved [i][j+1] = true;

                     System.out.println("Move Right");

                 }

                 else if ((i>13)||(i<9&&i>=7)){

                     if (numbers[i+4][j+5] == 1&&moved [i][j] == false){

                             numbers [i+5][j+5] = 1;

                             numbers [i+4][j+5] = 2;

                             moved [i-1][j] = true;

                             damage[i-1][j] = damage[i][j];

                             damage[i][j] = 0;

                             System.out.println("Move Up");

                     }

                     else if (numbers [i+6][j+5] == 1&&moved[i][j] == false){

                         numbers [i+5][j+5] = 1;

                         numbers [i+6][j+5] = 2;

                         moved [i+1][j] = true;

                         damage[i+1][j] = damage[i][j];

                         damage[i][j] = 0;

                         System.out.println("Move Down");

                     }

                 }

                 else if ((i<=13&&i>=10)||(i<7)){

                     if (numbers [i+6][j+5] == 1&&moved[i][j] == false){

                         numbers [i+5][j+5] = 1;

                         numbers [i+6][j+5] = 2;

                         moved [i+1][j] = true;

                         damage[i+1][j] = damage[i][j];

                         damage[i][j] = 0;

                         System.out.println("Move Down");

                     }

                     else if (numbers[i+4][j+5] == 1&&moved [i][j] == false){

                             numbers [i+5][j+5] = 1;

                             numbers [i+4][j+5] = 2;

                             moved [i-1][j] = true;

                             damage[i-1][j] = damage[i][j];

                             damage[i][j] = 0;

                             System.out.println("Move Up");

                     }

                 }

                 else if (j!=0){

                     if (numbers[i+5][j+4] == 1&&j!=0&&moved[i][j] == false){

                         numbers [i+5][j+5] = 1;


                         numbers [i+5][j+4] = 2;

                         moved[i][j-1] = true;

                         damage[i][j-1] = damage[i][j];

                         damage[i][j] = 0;

                         System.out.println("Move Left");

                     }

                 }

             }

         }

     }

     }

 }


 public void CheckOutputFile(){
          int number;

         try{

         output = new Scanner(ofile);

         }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

         System.out.println("ERROR: cannot open file hiscore.txt");

         fileexists = true;

        // System.exit(1);

         }

         if (fileexists){

                 hiscore = output.nextInt();

                 checkhiscore = true;

                 output.close();

                 }

         }

 public void MakeOutputFile ( ) {

   fargle = new File ("Hiscore.txt");

      try {

           makesOutput = new PrintWriter ( fargle );

   }catch ( IOException e ){

      System.out.println("Cannot create file to be written to");

      System.exit(1);

   }// end catch

      makesOutput.println("\nHiscore :\t" + attackspawn);

      makesOutput.println ( );

      System.exit(1);

 }// end method MakeOutput File

   class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

         System.out.println("RAWR");

               if (evt.getSource() == begin){

                         System.out.println("Button Pressed");

                         begin.setVisible(false);

                         selectmap.setVisible(false);

                         play = true;

                         start = true;

                         option = (String)selectmap.getSelectedItem();

                         System.out.println(option);

               }

              if (evt.getSource() == upgrade){

                  if (money>=50){

                      money+=-50;

                      laser+=1+(int)(laser*.1);

                  }

              }
  }

}

 }

 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m){

     int x = m.getX();

     int y = m.getY();

     for (int row = 0; row < 20; row ++){

         for (int col = 0; col < 20; col ++){

             if (x>30+col*22&&x<51+col*22&&y>30+row*22&&y<51+row*22){
                 if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 1&&money>200){

                     numbers [row+5][col+5] = 0;

                     money+=-200;

                     repaint();

                 }

                 else if (numbers [row+5][col+5] == 0&&money>50){

                     System.out.println(row+" " +col);

                     money+=-50;

                     numbers [row+5][col+5] = 3;

                     repaint();

                 }

             }

         }

     }

 }

 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m){}

 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m){}

 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m){}

 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m){}

}
```

Comment: I don't think many people are going to want to look through your entire program to find the method in question. Consider isolating your problem to just the problematic sections -- huge blocks of code like this will drive lots of helpful people away

Comment: Please remove every 2nd (blank) line from that source, and use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: As you are new, a tip: catch the exception and print the stacktrace. Locate in it the last of your code (class and line number) that was executed before the exception, and point us which one it is.

Comment: Please reduce your question to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Do you expect us to read through all your code?

Comment: @PhilippReichart I was thinking 'that was uncalled for' ..until I checked the length of the source.  With every redundant blank line removed, it is still over 500 lines.  So yeah, *good* call.

Comment: Please add e.printstacktrace() in the catch block when you try to instantiate the printwriter to see the full error stacktrace and paste it in a new pastebin http://pastebin.com/, bringing the link here :) .

Comment: Your teacher is *wrong*, because you're using an Applet.........

Comment: @eboix  The teacher might have been referring to normal system file permissions, but if they were also the one that said 'make it an applet' then there is cause to consider them a fool who is unworthy to teach others.

Comment: Yeah. I just felt like saying that a teacher was *wrong*. (With the italics. It's so much fun.)

Answer (score 3):

An untrusted applet is not permitted to read/write `File` objects on the client computer.

The alternatives are to:

1. Store the information on the server.
2. Digitally sign the applet and get the user to OK it when asked to trust it.
3. Deploy for a Plug-In 2 JRE and use the JNLP API services to mediate the file write.